# Defining functions: type constraints with more than one variable

Tags: haskell

Working with this function:

```
getK x y
    | y < 1 = error "Index can not be less than 1!"
    | y > length x = error "Index greater than array length"
    | otherwise    = x !! (y-1)
```

If I don't define a type, GHC is fine with it.

```
*Main> :info getK
 getK :: [a] -> Int -> a    -- Defined at main.hs:7:1
```

But suppose I write the type constraint as:

```
getK :: (Int b) => [a] -> b -> a
```

As far as I can tell, the above is what GHC inferred. But no, it produces the following error:

```
main.hs:6:10:
`Int' is applied to too many type arguments
In the type signature for `getK': getK :: Int b => [a] -> b -> a
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

My immediate reaction was that there must have been a problem by my not assigning a type to 'a'. (Although there shouldn't have been because GHC recognizes that 'a' can be any type. So I then tried:

```
getK :: (Num a, Ord a, Int b) => [a] -> b -> a
```

Another error...

```
main.hs:6:24:
`Int' is applied to too many type arguments
In the type signature for `getK':
  getK :: (Num a, Ord a, Int b) => [a] -> b -> a
```

Please help me understand the behavior here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Int` is a type, not a type class. Only type classes like `Num` and `Ord` can be used as type constraints. This is how your signature would be written:

```
getK :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

GHCI has a `:info` command (this can be abbreviated `:i`) that will tell you about types and type classes and compare what it has to say about `Int` vs what it says about `Num`:

```
λ> :i Int
data Int = GHC.Types.I# GHC.Prim.Int#   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
instance Bounded Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
instance Enum Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
instance Eq Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Num Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Ord Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Read Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
instance Real Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Show Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
λ> 
λ> 
λ> :i Num
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
```

Comment: I believe that Integral is a class, correct? getK :: (Integral b) => [a] -> b -> a doesn't work either.

Comment: @Chris: This is because `length :: [a] -> Int` so it can't match the `Int` against the more general type `Integral b => b`.

Comment: The type of `!!` is `[a] -> Int -> a`, so the it specifically has to be an `Int`.

Comment: Gotcha. And just so I understand the terminology, I'm inferring that type constraints (i.e. classes) can go in 'f:: (HERE)'. If 'Int' in [a] -> Int -> a isn't a type constraint, what is it called instead?

Comment: @Chris It is a type (as opposed to a type class which, as its name implies, is a class of types).

Comment: Type constraints go before `=>` like this `f :: ... constraints go here ... => ... rest of signature ...`. Type constraints just use type classes.

Comment: There are also functions like `genericLength` and `genericIndex` in `Data.List`, which have the types that you are looking for.